# Change matplotlib toolbar position

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to have the toolbar from a matplotlib figure be moved from it's default bottom position to the top?

I am using a wx backend.

Thanks.

Comment: @MattDMo : Sorry if I asked in a wrong way, but do you have any resource which can point me to the right direction?